# Unreal behavior of Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

For the most bizarre reason my Xcode UICollectionView decided it has no member reloaditems. The error occurs only if run on a simulator, but compiles NP on a device. Anyone has a clue? Or should I bugreport this one?

Please, if you downvote - provide some info such as (irrelevant, unreal, go reinstall your Xcode or upgrade your mac sort of thing)

Here is the error:

[image: here is the error]

The UICollectionView class in the UIKit:

[image: the UICollectionView class in the UIKit]

The two headers as they appear in the project:

[image: the two headers as they appear in the project]

EDIT: (following @Martin R comment)
simulator and device iOS version is 10.2
deployment target 10.1
Clean new project behaves the same. No such thing as reloadItems in the simulator UIKit UICollectionView.h file and therefore the error.

[image: error in build]

[image: autocomplete suggestion]

[image: error and suggestion as requested by @Martin R]

Comment: What is the iOS deployment target and the iOS version of the Simulator? What is the *full* error message (look into the Report navigator)? What "Fix it" does Xcode suggest (click on the red round icon with the white dot inside)?

Comment: Now the first and the last screenshot show different code ... Please post code and the corresponding error message as text. Try to reduce the code to a minimal example.

Comment: The first screenshot shows an error at `collectionView.reloadItems(at: selectedIndexPaths)` and the last at `self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [ip])`. That is not the same.

Comment: Dear,  @Martin R, it's a different code with the **same error**, anywhere in the project where I try to perform reloadItems on ANY collectionView - the xcode suggestion CHANGING the code into what it suggests. It wants me to put "deleteItems" instead of the reloadItems. Plus there is no more error code, this is the full error code, you can see it in the build summary. Here it is as text for your convenience: "value of type uicollectionview has no member reloaditems". Thank you

Comment: Create a new, single view, project. Add a `UICollectionView` to the view. Add a func that calls `reloadItems` - do you see the same problem?

Comment: Clean project behaves the same. No such thing as reloadItems in the simulator UIKit UICollectionView.h file and therefore the error.

Comment: If you are saying that the simulator SDK does not declare `reloadItems` but the native iOS SDK does, this must be a bug and should be reported to Apple.

Comment: Have you somehow edited the UICollectionView source? There is definitely not supposed to be this function: `func withRowAnimationems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])`

Comment: Dear @James P, I have no knowledge of a way for editing Apple's framework, such as UIKit, If I have accidentally done that, Apple, me and the whole community need to know how...

Comment: Time for a delete and re-install of Xcode I think